# How to reload one of multiple iframes on the page through javascript

Tags: javascript, iframe, menu, click

I have a set of menus and multiple iframes on the page (e.g. top / center / bottom).

The top and bottom iframes tend to stay with the same content most of the time.  I just want to reload the center iframe when clicking on different menus.

How could do I this via javascript when clicking on different menus?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Since you've given no details and how you've structured your HTML helping you is difficult.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
window.top.frames.CENTER.src = "http://google.com";
```

or grab iframe by id and update its source

```
document.getElementById("iframeCenter").src = "http://google.com"
```